# Store form input fields based on select value?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Whenever a user visit register page and when he is selecting his college but does not find his college then there is "other" option...

When he click on "other" an another input field is shown saying specify your college
Now the problem is i don't want to store "other" value in the database
if he chooses his college from select option then that value should be inserted but if he chooses "other" option then the value he writes in "specify" input should be stored in database

here is my code

```
   <select class="job-purpose" name="college" id="college" >
   <option selected="selected" value="">-</option>
   <option value="1">
   NID - National Institute Of Design</option>
   <option value="2">
   NIFT - National Institute Of fashion Technology</option>
   <option value="3">
   Pearl Academy Of Fashion</option>
   <option value="4">
   SOFT - School Of Fashion Technology</option>
   <option value="5">
   Srishti Institute Of Design</option>
   <option value="6">
   MITID</option>
   <option value="7">
   Arch Academy Of Design</option>
   <option value="8">
   Satyam Fashion Institute</option>
   <option value="9">
   NIIFT</option>
  <option value="10">
  UID - United World Institute Of Design</option>
  <option value="11">
  International College Of Fashion </option>
  <option value="12">
  Raffles</option>

  <option value="other">
  other</option>
   </select>
```

here is on change option code

```
    <div class="form-group" style="display:none;" id="coll">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="label-wrapper">
    <label class="control-label">College <span 
    class="vd_red">*</span></label>
    </div>

     <input type="text" name="coll" id="col" 
     placeholder="College Name">
     </div>
     </div>
```

Here is Javascript code

```
    < script type="text/javascript" >
 $('#college').change(function(){
  selection = $(this).val();    
   switch(selection)
   { 
   case 'other':
       $('#coll').show();
       break;
   default:
       $('#coll').hide();
       break;
   }
   });
 < /script >
```

PHP Part

```
    if(empty($looking)or empty($profession) or empty($experience)or    
    empty($current)or empty($state)or empty($jobtype)or empty($about)){ 

    if($college == 'others'){
    $coll= $_POST['coll'];
     unset($_POST['college']);
    $college= $coll;
     }
```

Comment: So what is the question ?

Comment: Are you storing college `id` in database or `college name` ? If `id` then you need to add specified college in college list table and then insert `id` in users table..

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
        $college = $_POST['college'];
        $coll = $_POST['coll'];
//this below line checks for is college selected and checks for the value selected not the "other" option
        if (isset($collage) && $collage != 'other') {
            //run your database query hear
        }elseif (isset($coll)) { //this line checks for the inputfiled coll isset if yes go to next line
            //run your database query hear
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Add more explanations to your answer.